# Display notes when hovering over ASP.NET buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, button, hover

I have a number of buttons on my page and I would like to have some kind of notes appearing next to it explaining what the button is for when they hover over any particular button.

How would I go about achieving that?

(I am after something similar to when you hover over the tags below on this stackoverflow page...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should do like this

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:Button id="button1" Text="Submit" runat="server"
ToolTip="This is an example-button"/>
</form>
```

Here tooltip shows your message.

Answer (score 1):

Tap into the hover of that item using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Attach a function to hover that shows and hides a div.  There are many examples of showing popup windows using jQuery.  A quick Google search took me [Here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).  You will also have to position the popup in the correct location.  You can get the correct location using jQuery as well. http://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using codeBehind, try this:

```
nameOfControlButton.ToolTip = "Here is my tooltip comment";
```

Comment: What if I need the "here is my tooltip" to be dynamic from the db based on what item is being hovered?